# No-cache and updating doesn't work in IE 10 with JSP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, internet-explorer, caching

I've turned off caching and manually retrieve statuses from a rest call in a jsp page using javascript. Everybody likes it (Chrome, FireFox, Safari, Opera), except IE 8-11, of course.

The bulk of the work is done by getStatus(). This uses an XMLHttpRequest to retrieve a set of json statuses from a REST call. It parses the json and copies the statuses to the innerHTML of the td tags. I use setInterval() to perform this every 5 seconds.

I turn off caching with Cache-Control, Pragma, and Expires headers, near the top of the jsp.

The symptoms are that the statuses never get updated.

Here is the code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<% 
//tell browsers and proxy servers not to cache this page
if ("HTTP/1.1".equals(request.getProtocol()))
{
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
}
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache" );
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
%>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Application Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>/css/Admin.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    // need enough time for jbehave to parse the page
    var REFRESH = 5000; // 5 seconds

        // Update status after 5 seconds has elapsed.
    setInterval("jobStatus();", REFRESH);

    function jobStatus() {
        getStatus();
    }

    function getStatus() {
        var xhttpRequest = getXMLHttpRequest();
        xhttpRequest.open("GET", "<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>/admin/resyncPhs/getstatus",  true);
        xhttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttpRequest.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhttpRequest.status === 200) {
                     var json = xhttpRequest.responseText;
                     var parsed = JSON.parse(json);

                     document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = parsed.status;
                     document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML = parsed.progress;
                }
            }
        };
        xhttpRequest.send(null);
    }

    function getXMLHttpRequest() {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            return new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }

</script>

</head>
<body onLoad="jobStatus();">
                <table class="resyncBodyTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td />
                        <td>Labels:</td>
                        <td id="status">${status}</td>
                        <td id="progress">${progress}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE requires more persuasion than other browsers:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
```

Comment: Will those parameters cause problems with other browsers, or do they need to only be applied to IE?

Comment: They wont cause problems in other browsers.